# How Entity framework works with lambda-expressions in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda

I'm working with EF code first. There are two classes which define my many to many association  tables:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Habit> Habits { get; set; }
}



public class Habit
{
    [Key]
    public int HabitId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I need to select from my database all habits for current user. I'm very new to c#, and the problem is that I can't understand how to work with complex lambda-expressions. I tried that:

```
context.Habits.Where(habit => habit.Users
                .Where(user=>user.Email==User.Identity.Name)).ToList()
```

But it's wrong. Could you please correct my lambda-based query. Thanks.

Comment: user.Email==User.Identity.Name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add a `DbSet<UserProfile>` to your context and then do:

```
context.Users.Include("Habits")
       .First(user => user.Email == User.Identity.Name)
       .Habits;
```

If you want to avoid the above and rather fix the query you should do:

```
context.Habits.Where(habit =>                   
           habit.Users.Any(user=>user.Email==User.Identity.Name)).ToList();
```

`Any` returns true if any item in the IEnumerable satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Select (or SelectMany if you want a single flattened list)  for the first lambda expression:

```
context.Habits.Select(habit =>
    habit.Users.Where(user => user.Email == User.Identity.Name)
    ).ToList()
```

The problem is that `Where` requires that the lambda expression return a boolean, and it was returning an `IEnumerable<UserProfile>`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to **select** a specific property (`Habits`) from the `UserProfile` entity the most straight-forward way would be to use `Select` in my opinion:

```
var habits = context.UserProfiles
    .Where(user => user.Email == User.Identity.Name)
    .Select(user => user.Habits)
    .SingleOrDefault(); // I assume here that the Email is unique
```